# How can I optimize Python code to produce and filter over a very big list of active urls using multiprocessing? [code very slow]

Tags: performance, python-requests, multiprocessing

1) The goal of my code is to check around 400k urls if they are active and from this produce a csv file of all the urls which are active. Below code using multiprocessing is running fine on smaller subset of urls but is very slow on the complete set of urls.

2) I am looking for ideas on how to optimize and mainly speed up the code. Even after it has looped over all the urls it is still taking a very long time to filter out the results and produce the csv file. 
I had a few times that the code crashed and I am also looking for a way to make sure that the links it already has checked are not being lost.

3) The only thing that I can think of at the moment is subdividing the urls list and producing multiple csv files which I merge later. This will ensure already intermediate results but I doubt it will speed things up.

```
import requests
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import pandas as pd 

urls = ["%.7d" % i for i in range(8700000,8300000,-1)]

def get_status(url):
    r = requests.get(r'https://www.somesite.be/'+url)
    print(url)
    return r.status_code, url


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = ThreadPool(10)  # Make the Pool of workers
    results = pool.map(get_status, urls) #Open the urls in their own threads
    ids = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 200, results))
    ids_1 = list(map(lambda x: x[1], ids))
    df = pd.DataFrame(ids_1)
    df.to_csv('ids.csv', index=False)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Might be asked on [codereview.se] as your code doesn't have a practical problem.